# jQuery get request not returning anything

Tags: jquery, get

I have the following jQuery script, which is supposed to get data from a web-location.

First step is to load the data ... (after that I will have to do something with the data.)

My problem is the first step. The stuff simply doesn't load.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

         <script>

            $(document).ready(function(){

                var url = "http://vsr.informatik.tu-chemnitz.de/edu/2015/evs/exercises/jsajax/guestbook.php";
                $.get(url, function(data){
                    alert("test");      
                });

            });

        </script>
```

This script does not alert "test". My question is: why not? What's wrong?

Comment: What errors do you get in the browser's console? My suspicion is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Answer (score 1):

Your request has been blocked by CORS policy, due this you can't continue to the next statement.

This is a introduction to cors:

> CORS is industry standard for accessing web resources on different
>   domains. It is very important security concept implemented by web
>   browsers to prevent Javascript or CSS code from making requests
>   against a different origin.
>
> Let’s consider this scenario:
>
> You have link from Domain1 which is opened in browser and asking for a
>   JavaScript file from Domain2. Now your web browser makes call to
>   Domain2. If on Domain2, you have a policy to accept request like
>   JavaScript or CSS from only Domain2 and ignore all requests from
>   another domains, then your browser’s Domain1 request will fail with an
>   error. In simple statement: If request is not coming from same domain
>   or origin, just simply ignore it.
>
> This is very important features which prevents hacking and resource
>   stealing without owners’s knowledge.

To continue with success the origin host needs to send `Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` header to allow the request/response.

Reference:

[HTTP access control (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

[How to fix Access-Control-Allow-Origin (CORS origin) Issue for your HTTPS enabled WordPress Site and MaxCDN](http://crunchify.com/how-to-fix-access-control-allow-origin-issue-for-your-https-enabled-wordpress-site-and-maxcdn/)

Answer (score 0):

So what is happening probably is the security of your browser not allowing cross domain ajax calls. In other words, since you probably are not on the same domain as "tu-chemnitz.de", the browser is blocking your ajax request. A way to solve this to turn off the security of your browser. But if you have to resort to this, you need to rethink what you are doing. Users of your website are definitely not turning off their browser security because you are trying to do "dodgy" things.